# Spring data util pair rename json name

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

my first post here. I'm working on a API and i found a trouble that i don´t know how to solve it.
I´m trying to get the remaining stock of all products in my database. I´m using Spring boot and MongoDB with the Spring Data dependency.
Here is my code:

```
@GetMapping("/remaining-stock")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Pair<String, Integer>>> showAllStock() throws EmptyDepositException{
        List<Pair<String, Integer>> allStock;
        try {
            allStock = depServ.showAllStock();
        }catch(EmptyDepositException ex) {
            allStock = null;
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(allStock);
    }
```

When i do that GET request, this is the JSON i get:

```
[
    {
        "first": "Water",
        "second": 5
    },
    {
        "first": "Milk",
        "second": 40
    }
]
```

The values are OK but i want to rename the variables names with a better name like this:

```
[
    {
        "Product name": "Water",
        "Remaining stock": 5
    },
    {
        "Product name": "Milk",
        "Remaining stock": 40
    }
]
```

There is a way to do that?

Sorry for my english, i'm from Argentina so maybe something is not clear. I hope you can help me.
Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You should use a DTO instead of a Pair then you can name the attributes however you want

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@JsonProperty annotation` which indicates that the `field name` is used as the property name without any modifications, but it can be specified to non-empty value to specify different name. Property name refers to name used externally, as the `field name` in JSON objects.

```
public class Product implements Serializable {

    @JsonProperty("Product name")
    private String first;

    @JsonProperty("Remaining stock")
    private long second;

    // implement methods for getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Pair Class, you can't do that. I suggest you to create a DTO class like below :

```
public class CustomPair {
    @JsonProperty("Product name")
    private String first;
    @JsonProperty("Remaining stock")
    private String second;

    // standard getters and setters
}
```

Then your controller will be like this :

```
@GetMapping("/remaining-stock")
    public ResponseEntity<List<CustomPair>> showAllStock() throws EmptyDepositException{
        List<CustomPair> allStock;
        try {
            allStock = depServ.showAllStock(); // depServ.showAllStock(); should return List<CustomPair>
        }catch(EmptyDepositException ex) {
            allStock = null;
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(allStock);
    }
```